# Data is not stored into $_POST array from ajax request

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post

So I've already done an AJAX request using GET, and so now i wanted to try my luck using POST instead. But for some reason, when i try to send data, I get a crazy weird message in the console - NS_ERROR_XPC_JSOBJECT_HAS_NO_FUNCTION_NAMED: 'JavaScript component does not have a method named: "available"' when calling method: [nsIInputStream::available] 
I literally have no idea what this means, and I know the data isnt going through because all im doing in the load.php file that I request is echo the variable its supposed to store. So its something in the javascript.

Here is my HTML for the first page that makes the request.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<input id="input">

<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

And my Javascript:

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  var data = "id="+document.getElementById("input").value;
xmlhttp.open("POST","load.php",true);
xmlhttp.send(data);
}
```

And finally, the code for load.php:

```
$param = $_POST['id'];
if($param){
        echo "Variable was stored.";
    } else{
        echo "Not working";
    }
```

And everytime i run this, i get "not working" in the browser. So the php code is at least attempting to store the variable, but its not. Thankyou!

Comment: Have you tried just `print_r` on `$_POST` to see what it contains?

Comment: It outputs "Array ( )" and thats it. I thought of something after I posted the question however, could it be that if accessing through POST the input would have to be within a <form> and submitted? Or is it required that it is in a form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your forgot to add `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')`. With this line we are basically saying that the data send is in the format of a form submission

```
function loadXMLDoc()
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
          var data = "id="+document.getElementById("input").value;

        xmlhttp.open("POST","load.php",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xmlhttp.send(data);
    }
```

Comment: Wow, that was exactly it! Thanks so much! I saw that in an example somewhere but didn't figure that it was required! Thanks again!